# Creation of a "TIE-aircraft" tag?

Tags: discussion

Since I do not have the rep here to create tags, I was wondering if it would be possible for someone to create a "TIE-aircraft" tag.

Since this is very specific, applicable to a well-known galaxy, and at least to Imperial Naval aviators a topic of significant interest, it does seem that it would be useful in this community.

Answer (score 7):

No, this is a highly specific in-universe object (or class of object) and we generally avoid those as tags. It would also lead to similar tags for other ships (Star Destroyers? Constitution class cruisers?), and then probably other non-ship things. It'd be too messy, difficult to manage and track.

One way to tag such questions instead is [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) + [vehicles](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicles).